# Where to store NLog log files on Xamarin Android?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, nlog

In a [tutorial](https://damienaicheh.github.io/xamarin/nlog/2019/06/06/monitor-your-xamarin-application-using-nlog-en.html), I followed some steps to integrate NLog into our Xamarin (non Forms) application. In there the folder to store the log files is ${specialfolder:folder=MyDocuments}. If I change that folder to e.g. /sdcard/Download I see that a logs folder is created and I can access / copy the log files.

```
C:\Users\bachph>C:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe pull /sdcard/Download/logs/ D:\temp
/sdcard/Download/logs/: 2 files pulled. 5.4 MB/s (2077256 bytes in 0.370s)
```

If I now change the folder back to ${specialfolder:folder=MyDocuments} and print the path to that folder

```
LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger().Info("NLog.config loaded. Application Start.");
LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger().Info($"NLog logs to {Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)}");
```

I can't see the data in the shell nor can I access / copy them from that folder. I'm now not sure if I Android just permits the access to the folder / files or if NLog can't write to that folder.

Any ideas?

---

Edit: internal trace log output

```
2019-10-07 11:39:47.6959 Debug FileTarget(Name=f): Process file '/data/data/de.app.debug/files/logs/app-2019-10-07.log' on startup
2019-10-07 11:39:47.7298 Debug Creating file appender: /data/data/de.app.debug/files/logs/app-2019-10-07.log
2019-10-07 11:39:47.7377 Debug Mutex for file archive not supported
2019-10-07 11:39:47.7439 Trace Opening data/data/de.app.debug/files/logs/app-2019-10-07.log with allowFileSharedWriting=False
2019-10-07 11:39:47.6440 INFO App.Activities.Base.MainActivity NLog.config loaded. Application Start.
```

Comment: To find out what going on, switch on [internal logging](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging). If the path isn't valid (which would be my first guess), it should be visible there.

Comment: I added some log output. From that, I would say that he created a log file. In the NLog.config I have the configuration autoReload="false", throwExceptions="true", internalLogToConsole="true", internalLogLevel="Trace".

Comment: Seems that the data is written correctly. It is a permission problem. Android does not permit the view of the data via shell. And as the run-as command always printed "unknown package", I had to found another solution to access the data. See my other post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a way to access the data inside of the /data/data folder. Unfortunately it is a bit tricky to accees the data.

First of all the "run-as" command does not work on my device. So I have to create a "Backup" to get all data from the app.

You can create a backup with:

```
adb.exe backup -f D:\temp\backup.ab -noapk de.app.debug
adb.exe backup -f <path-to-local-file> -noapk <app-base-package>
```

You will be promt to confirm the action on your device. Optionally you can chose a password for the backup file.

That will create an android backup. To access the data inside the backup file, you need the help of a [java archive](https://github.com/nelenkov/android-backup-extractor/releases). Get the latest abe-all.jar from there.

You can now convert the android backup into a tar archive with

```
java -jar abe-all.jar unpack backup.ab backup.tar [optional-password]
```

Then simply extract the newly created backup.tar file. You'll find all data from your app package in there.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative way of accessing log-files on Xamarin platform is to save in special-folder My Documents.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/ (See `System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments`)

NLog has `${specialfolder:folder=MyDocuments}`. See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Special-Folder-Layout-Renderer

Then make a feature in the application to read the current log-file from the folder, and send to email-app or make http-upload (Or just show the log-content directly in the application-about-dialog).

Alternative one could use [NLog.Targets.MauiLog](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Targets.MauiLog) that supports platform specific output:

- Android - Android.Util.Log / LogCat
- Apple iOS / MacOS - Unified Logging OSLog (replacement of print and NSLog)

Comment: Andriod does not have my documents it only has my files i cant find them